# From byte[] to XmlTextReader

Tags: c#

my question is pretty simple, I've an array of bytes (fullfilled via Sockets) and I would like transform it into a XmlTextReader object. How can I do this?

This doesn't work :

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[5000]; // TODO a revoir
int sizeReceived;

sizeReceived = _socket.Receive(buffer);
string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, sizeReceived); // s is correctly fulfilled with XML a get back
MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(buffer);
memory.Position = 0;

return new XmlTextReader(memory);
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set start and end index of stream.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[5000]; // TODO a revoir
int sizeReceived;

sizeReceived = _socket.Receive(buffer);
MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, sizeReceived);
return new XmlTextReader(memory);
```